# Array returning empty in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

This is all still pretty new to me but I am running into an interesting behavior issue when generating an array of numbers in a NodeJS application that handles .nessus result files. First, some details on what I am trying to accomplish. My application generates an array [1234,1223,1222] of entries from an uploaded "results" file that is then used to query a mongodb instance to determine if those entries are currently in the DB. If those entries are not currently in the mongodb instance, it redirects to a page where a user can edit them before being added. If there are no new entries, it goes to a page to generate a report on the entries.

When a file is uploaded, it stores the new entries. In .nessus files, sometimes there is more than one host with entries. That changes the json structure and the function needs to iterate a little differently. The following function is how those entries are stored. **This is important as this is where the weird behavior originates (I think)**

```
function parsePluginNumbers(json){

    var pluginNumbers = []

    //Let's check the number of hosts
    var hostLength = json['NessusClientData_v2']['Report'].ReportHost.length

    if (hostLength != undefined) {
        for (var i = 0; i < hostLength; i++) { //Since there is more than 1, need to iterate over each host to find the findings.
            var item_length = json['NessusClientData_v2']['Report'].ReportHost[i].ReportItem.length
            for (var t = 0; t < item_length; t++) { //Iterate through each finding on each host
                if (json['NessusClientData_v2']['Report'].ReportHost[i].ReportItem[t].risk_factor != 'None') { 
                    var newEntry = json['NessusClientData_v2']['Report'].ReportHost[i].ReportItem[t].pluginID
                    if (pluginNumbers.indexOf(newEntry) == -1) {
                        pluginNumbers.push(newEntry)
                    }
                    else {
                        continue
                    }
                } else {
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        var item_length = json['NessusClientData_v2']['Report']['ReportHost'].ReportItem.length
        for (var t = 0; t < item_length; t++) { //Iterate over findings 
                if (json['NessusClientData_v2']['Report']['ReportHost'].ReportItem[t].risk_factor != 'None') { 
                    var newEntry = json['NessusClientData_v2']['Report']['ReportHost'].ReportItem[t].pluginID
                    if (pluginNumbers.indexOf(newEntry) == -1) {
                        pluginNumbers.push(newEntry)
                    }
                    else {
                        continue
                    }
                } else {
                    continue
                }
        }
    }
    return pluginNumbers    
}
```

Once those plugins are stored. Another function is called to look if those results are in the mongodbinstance. In this function, those plugins are in an array "pluginsTotal".

```
    function queryForNewResultsInANessusFile(pluginsTotal, collectionname, filename){ //function to call mongodb query and send results to parseNewFindings and parseOldFindings.
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get(collectionname);

    collection.find({ 'PluginNumber' : { $in: pluginsTotal }}, 'FindingTitle FindingDescription Remediation Mitigation SeeAlso PluginFamily PluginNumber CVE Risk -_id', function(error, result){
        var newPluginArray = parseOutFindingNumbersInMongoDB(result, pluginsTotal);


//IF statements go here with specific redirects as needed to check if there are new values not in the repo
}
```

During this collection.find call, there is a function parseOutFindingNumbersInMongoDB that is called to determine if there are plugins in the .nessus results file that are not in the repo. It compares the results from collection.find and pluginsTotal (generated from the first function) and returns an array of the new plugins that are not in the repo. The function details are below:

```
function parseOutFindingNumbersInMongoDB(repoResults, reportPlugins) {

    for (var i = 0; i < repoResults.length; i++){
        var index = reportPlugins.indexOf(repoResults[i].PluginNumber);
        if (index != -1) {
            reportPlugins.splice(index, 1);
            }
        else {
            continue
            }
    }
    return reportPlugins
}
```

Now to my question --- When I upload a .nessus file with more than one host, parseOutFindingNumberInMongoDB always returns empty even though there are new entries. What gives? Is it the way I parse out the numbers to begin with in the parsePluginNumbers function or is because it is called in the collection.find synchronous function (This seems unlikely as if there is one host, it returns the new plugin values as I want)? Any thoughts/ideas/review would be much appreciated as I cannot figure out what is wrong. I have checked the data types within the array before being passed into the functions and they all match up.

Comment: Could you please try and create a [mcve]? Your example fails on the "C" part, since it is missing the input data, and I suspect it also fails on the "M" part, since I highly doubt it requires 60 lines of code (plus an unknown amount of JSON) plus a MongoDB database to demonstrate your problem. I'm guessing, 10 lines would be enough.

Comment: Hey @JörgWMittag, thanks for the comment. First, I highly doubt it requires 60 lines of code too but I am new to this and this is the only way I know. Second, from your comment, I went ahead, found some motivation and dug in deep and figured a better way of accomplishing what I needed done and then some. Lastly, thanks for pointing out the MCV criteria. Now I know better for further questions I may post on here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's always returning an empty array because every element in the array matches the condition to be spliced.

You first retrieve elements that have a `PluginNumber` in `pluginTotal` array with this filter `{ $in: pluginsTotal }`

```
collection.find({ 'PluginNumber' : { $in: pluginsTotal }}, 'FindingTitle FindingDescription Remediation Mitigation SeeAlso PluginFamily PluginNumber CVE Risk -_id', function(error, result){
    var newPluginArray = parseOutFindingNumbersInMongoDB(result, pluginsTotal);
}
```

Then you remove all elements that have a `PluginNumber` in `pluginTotal`

```
    var index = reportPlugins.indexOf(repoResults[i].PluginNumber);
    if (index != -1) {
        reportPlugins.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

So the result is always an empty array.